# Azure Cloud Service continuous integration with existing ccproj profile

Tags: azure, msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

How do I get continuous integration to work using publish settings from a profile in our Cloud Project?

[image: Cloud Project Development profile]

When using the default `TfvcContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml`, the publish ignores some of my profile settings. It doesn't use the correct storage account and always publishes to the Staging environment.

Here are the settings for my Development publish profile:

[image: Publish Profile]

Here is the current state of our build definition:

[image: Build Definition]

"Path to Deployment Settings" sounds like it would be correct but it is [only for Azure Websites](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/).

How do I get this to publish using all profile settings as specified in my .azurePubxml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CI template `TfvcContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml` will not use your publishing profile. Relevant settings (deployment slot, storage account name, ...) are configured in `6. Deployment > Deployment > Windows Azure Deployment Environment`

[image]

`/p:TargetProfile=Development` specifies service configuration only (selects correct .cscfg file), not a publishing profile.

If you need to configure additional features like for example remote debugging, you will have to add [additional msbuild parameters](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-virtual-machines-dotnet-continuous-delivery-remote-debugging/) in `2. Build > 5. Advanced > MSBuild arguments`.

Comment: Thanks.  For some reason I never saw that dialog. I was previously typing my cloud service name directly into that field.