# AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml vs TfvcContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml

Tags: azure, msbuild, tfsbuild, azure-web-roles, azure-devops

I can't seem to find any information regarding the difference between these two build definition templates:

- **`AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml`**
- **`TfvcContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml`**

My guess is that `AzureContinuousDeployment` has been replaced by `TfvcContinuousDeploymentTemplate`.

Does this mean I should not use `AzureContinuousDeployment`?  I want to use it because here I am able to set the storage account, deployment label and environment (Production/Staging).

I can't find a way to set this with `TfvcContinuousDeploymentTemplate`.

I am releasing to Azure Cloud Services (web roles).

Comment: did you find a useful answer to your question? I have the same question and want a simple answer.

Comment: No, but I've moved away from the xaml builds to using the new vnext build platform.

Comment: @RuSs: Refer to the latest answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml

  - This is meant to be used by a TFS 2012 build controller.
- TfvcContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml

  - This is meant to be used by a TFS 2013 build controller.

TfvcContinuousDeploymentTemplate is a replacement for AzureContinuousDeployment.

It was a few additional functionalities, one of them is the new nuget package restore process.

There is also another build system which microsoft is recommended people move to called VNext Build that is out in TFS 2015

Answer (score 0):

So, these settings can actually be specified in the `Windows Azure Deployment Environment` field in the build definition.

More information can be found in my [Stackoverflow post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942252/azure-cloud-service-continuous-integration-with-existing-ccproj-profile).

I still don't know what the difference is between these two templates.